# How can I get total hits from a Google Analytics Account?

Tags: google-analytics, automation

I need to get GMP (Google Marketing Platform) Usage Hits information from some specific organizations.

Currently, I am doing this manually going to GMP portal, administration, selecting the organization and seeing their total hits usage from Google Analytics.

How can I automate this? I only need to get the total hits value from an account.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it at level Account. You can make an estimate by adding the hits received in the last 30 days from each account property.

Go to the Admin panel, then at the Property level, then choose Property Settings. Scroll down to **Property Hit Volume**.

Comment: Does GMP have a API or can we use Puppeteer inside?

Comment: Not that I know.